# Error After running protractor in eclipse

Tags: jhipster

I am trying to run protractor in jhipster using eclipse.
After I right clicked on protractor.conf.js file in src/main/test/javascript and run as run Configurations. Showing error as Below.

Error while launching client file
Cannot find client file.